# How can I change default settings for new users?

Tags: 11.10, dconf, gsettings

Every key in the DConf database has a default value that is used when user accounts are created. How can I change these default values?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Install the package [dconf-tools[image: Install dconf-tools]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools). <--click or run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
   ```
2. Run `dconf-editor` and navigate to the key you want to change the default for. Note the *Schema* name, in this example that is `com.canonical.Unity.Launcher`:

   [image]
3. Now we need to create an override file. Run the following command:

   ```
   gksu gedit /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/my-defaults.gschema.override
   ```

   <sup>You can use any name you want for the file, it just needs to end in `gschema.override`</sup>
4. Write your new defaults in this file in standard [INI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) format, using schemas for groups names:

   ```
   [com.canonical.Unity.Launcher]

   favorites=['nautilus-home.desktop', 'google-chrome.desktop', 'banshee.desktop', 'gnome-terminal.desktop', 'ubuntu-software-center.desktop', 'ubuntuone-installer.desktop', 'gnome-tweak-tool.desktop', 'gpodder.desktop', 'shutter.desktop']
   ```
5. Save the file and close it. Now run the following command from a terminal to apply your changes:

   ```
   sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
   ```

Comment: You can also search for a scheme, key or value using gesettings together with grep. E.g. to find all launcher items: `gsettings list-recursively | grep launcher`