# Ubuntu doesn't retain mouse cursor size between reboots

Tags: cursor, restart, dconf

I'm having an annoying problem here, every time I boot system, I have to manually set my cursor size from 24 to 16, I can't seem to find a way to save... make that 16 permanent even after boot, does anyone know how to do that?
Using Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit.
[image]

Answer (score 8):

I was facing the same issue, then found a similar entry under **/com/canonical/unity/interface/cursor-scale-factor**, increased to 1.20 and it worked fine after reboot.
Too bad there's no option under Universal Access or something :S

Comment: Perfectly working for `Ubuntu 16.04.1`, thanks! This also fixes the bug that some applications scaled the cursor back down.

Comment: You're right. This should definitely be available in [Universal Access](https://i.imgur.com/UWR4AYf.png).

Comment: I guess you could probably accomplish this also with this command: gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Interface cursor-scale-factor 1.2

Answer (score 4):

First note that it is necessary that the theme used in Ubuntu allows the size corresponding to the cursor size.

Therefore, do:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size 16
```

(or other size, 24, 48, as the theme permits)

But only with this command size will be lost when you restart the session or the system, then to become permanent:

```
cd /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
```

Make a backup copy of the compiled file of the schemes:

```
sudo mv gschemas.compiled gschemas.compiled-bak
```

Then change the default value:

```
sudo gedit org.gnome.desktop.interface.gschema.xml
```

Locate this block:

￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ <key name="cursor-size" type="i"
>

￰
 ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ <default>**24**</default>

￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ <summary>Cursor size</summary>

￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ <description>Size of the cursor used as cursor theme.</description>

￰￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ </key>

Change the value above 24 to 16, 48, 96, that's all, do not change anything.

Save and Exit

Make a new compilation of existing schemes:

```
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

This should have generated a new file with the name gschemas.compiled within the directory in question.

Restart the session and / or the system.

The mouse cursor should remain in the chosen size.