# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Unable to resize mouse pointer

Tags: 16.04, desktop-environments, resize, mouse-pointer

I come to you for a help figuring out hot to resize a mouse pointer on the OS for a disabled family member who is unable to see very well.

The OS: 64-but Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop

It's a default installation with Unity Desktop.

The problem: The cursor (mouse pointer on the screen) is too small for visually impaired user to see on the screen.

What I have done so far:

1. I added config parameter to ~/.Xresources with the content: Xcursor.size:48
2. Executed: gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size 48
3. Update alternative for the cursor theme to a manual (default)

So far the result is that the mouse pointer becomes larger... however the setting is not retained through OS reboot. Once OS restarts, the cursor becomes small again (default size 24) and checking: 
 gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size

... returns the default of 24.

Could anyone please advise me how to make the setting to stick and stay at 48 through the OS reboot.

I would really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: It not keeping through reboot seems a confirmed bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1530683

Comment: Is there a work around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use unity-tweak-tool.

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

In **Appearance > Cursors** there is a "Use large cursors" check box.

This makes a cursor that would be large enough for most disabled persons.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. In my particular case and needs it actually did produced large enough cursor.

Comment: Doesn't persist.

Comment: Do you have to reboot for this to take effect?

Answer (score 1):

I found that changing "cursor-scale-factor" in dconf Editor [com>canonical>unity>interface] would make a mouse cursor size change hold on reboot (running Ubuntu 16.04). If you check back to "cursor-size" in dconf you can see what resultant change "cursor-scale-factor" does as it is reciprocal. So 48 would be a scale factor of 2.0

(see also link below)

[Ubuntu doesn't retain mouse cursor size between reboots](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770915/ubuntu-doesnt-retain-mouse-cursor-size-between-reboots)

Comment: I've installed, but no "appearance > cursors" to be find.