# Fix pointer size in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mouse, mouse-pointer

I am running Ubuntu 18.04, and after playing with the graphical settings I ended up having a different pointer size outside and outside of opened windows (see image below). I already tried changing the size in Tweaks and following what described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130324/mouse-pointer-size-inconsistent) but I had no success. I took care of rebooting between steps. How do you suggest to fix this?

[image]

Comment: I guess I can but I'm a bit lost. How do you suggest to proceed?

Comment: I can select a different size in system settings, but it doesn't change the cursor size in the wild (outside of a window).

Comment: Thanks! Cursor theme: DMZ-White (`/usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme` from `sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme`). Screen resolution: 3840x2160. Cursor size: 24.

Comment: Could this be due to `sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop`, followed by `sudo apt remove ubuntu-unity-desktop`? I gave that command a while ago.

Comment: can you have a look on this https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOzTP.gif . from where did you get the value for Cursor size: 24..

Comment: Sorry 40. I set it via `dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/cursor-size 40`

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyonn.gif have a look.. dconf-editor and system-settings.. when i select the cursor sizes on system settings.. the value for dconf-editor also changing.. i suggest you to download a cursor theme which is have a high value from gnome-look.org and see..

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and found out that it was caused by selecting lightdm from the display managers when I installed lxde on my computer.

I removed lightdm and reinstalled it, this time selecting GTK3 from the list.

Back to normal mouse pointer sizes.