# How do I fix the icons after manually installing LibreOffice 4.0?

Tags: unity, icons, libreoffice

I removed the previous version of Libreoffice and installed the current Libreoffice 4.0 from [libreoffice.org/download](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/). But now the icons and global-menubar are inactive: see screenshot.

[image: libre-error]

<sup>Click on the image to open a full-resolution version.</sup>

After the first time, I removed Libreoffice 4.0, and restarted, then installed it manually again. The script below is what I used both times.

```
sudo apt-get -y remove libreoffice*

cd /tmp
wget http://download.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/stable/4.0.0/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_4.0.0_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz
tar -xvf LibreOffice_4.0.0_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz
cd LibreOffice_4.0.0.3_Linux_x86-64_deb/DEBS
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
cd desktop-integration
sudo dpkg -i *.deb

cd /tmp

wget http://download.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/stable/4.0.0/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_4.0.0_Linux_x86-64_deb_langpack_nl.tar.gz
tar -xvf LibreOffice_4.0.0_Linux_x86-64_deb_langpack_nl.tar.gz
cd LibreOffice_4.0.0.3_Linux_x86-64_deb_langpack_nl/DEBS
sudo dpkg -i *.deb

cd /tmp
wget http://download.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/stable/4.0.0/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_4.0.0_Linux_x86-64_deb_helppack_nl.tar.gz
tar -xvf LibreOffice_4.0.0_Linux_x86-64_deb_helppack_nl.tar.gz
cd LibreOffice_4.0.0.3_Linux_x86-64_deb_helppack_nl/DEBS
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

**Question**: *How do I get the standard icons back?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you've got LibreOffice's high contrast icons which happens if LibreOffice doesn't like something about your gtk theme. You can for check that in Tools > Options > View. Note the image below is from LibreOffice 3.6 and not 4.0:

[image: LibO's icons]

Here are two links that indicate what Unity integration is required:

- [LibreOffice 4.0 Unity Integration in
  12.04](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2113397)
- [LibreOffice 4.0 Unity Integration in Ubuntu
  12.04](http://nabble.documentfoundation.org/LibreOffice-4-0-Unity-Integration-in-Ubuntu-12-04-td4035137.html)

Comment: you perhaps can give a pointer in your answer - look at the ubuntu modifications in the preview libreoffice PPA - this will need to be merged & compiled into the standard libreoffice source.

Comment: Thanks vasa1 that fixed the icon issue! i will ask the global-menu not working in a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

To get standard icons back on launcher please follow instructions:
[How can I change default settings for new users?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65900/how-can-i-change-default-settings-for-new-users)

Ubuntu's default favorites are:

`['ubiquity-gtkui.desktop', 'nautilus-home.desktop', 'firefox.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'libreoffice-calc.desktop', 'libreoffice-impress.desktop', 'ubuntu-software-center.desktop', 'ubuntuone-installer.desktop', 'gnome-control-center.desktop']`

But after installation of LO 4.0 correct names would be `libreoffice4.0-writer.desktop`, `libreoffice4.0-calc.desktop` and `libreoffice4.0-impress.desktop`.

After compilation of scheme you can reset launcher icons to default using:

`gsettings reset com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites`

or customize current user's launcher icons by setting value of `favorites` key, e.g.:

`gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['ubiquity-gtkui.desktop', 'nautilus-home.desktop', 'firefox.desktop', 'libreoffice4.0-writer.desktop', 'libreoffice4.0-calc.desktop', 'libreoffice4.0-impress.desktop', 'ubuntu-software-center.desktop', 'ubuntuone-installer.desktop', 'gnome-control-center.desktop']"`

for new default icons.

Answer (score 0):

0 down vote

You might want to try a version built specifically for Ubuntu. There are 4.0.1-rc1 packages in ricotz's LibreOffice Backports PPA https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/ppa

It says, however:

> THIS IS THE STAGING FOR THE OFFICIAL LIBREOFFICE PPA. The pacakges
>   will be copied there if they turn out well.
>
> INPROGRESS: LibreOffice 4.0 for Precise/12.04 and Quantal/12.10

Apparently they are building the Quantal version (Raring's is already done) of the for the official LibreOffice PPA at the time I am writing this. You should find it soon here: https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/libreoffice-4-0