# Fix gear icon in Libreoffice 4 from ppa

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, libreoffice, ppa

I installed libreoffice 4 from the supply debs in their website, because it didn't have unity integration I decided to completely uninstall it.
Today I saw the ppa has libreoffice 4 with support for unity, so I installed it from the ppa.

The problem I have is with the icons in the side-bar once the programs are launched, calc and writer but not the main libreoffice.
I can see the icons in the dash, but not in the side bar, I only see a gear and there's no context menu for them either, just the option to lock or quit, not even the name of the program.

I followed this guide: http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=101&t=48319#p227823
It actually works, every time I open any of the applications, the icons are correctly displayed and also their context menu, but as soon as I delete the desktop icons, the gear is back again without context menu.
I don't want to have libreoffice icons on my desktop.

I also tried just drag and drop from the dash to the side bar, but when I start calc or writer, a new gear icon appears instead of using the already displayed libreoffice icon.

Does anybody has any idea of what's going on?

Comment: Might [this question on the standard icons](http://askubuntu.com/questions/252687/how-do-i-fix-the-icons-after-manually-installing-libreoffice-4-0/257975#257975) help you with your issue?

Comment: it wasn't that... but that was a close call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have to restart your computer. Then you'll be able to right-click and select to keep the icon on the Launcher.

Comment: I did restarted, but it didn't work. Still having the same problem. Then after some packages got updated (don't know which ones) and a restart it works one