# How to remove all online smart scopes completely and permanently?

Tags: scopes

I want to remove all unitiy scopes, that may access the internet completely and permanently form a pool of many Ubuntu 13.10 machines. How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, the best thing to do is to unintall the packages:

```
sudo apt-get purge unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks unity-scope-colourlovers unity-scope-deviantart unity-scope-gallica unity-scope-gdrive unity-scope-github unity-scope-gmusicbrowser unity-scope-googlenews unity-scope-gourmet unity-scope-musicstores unity-scope-musique unity-scope-openclipart unity-scope-openweathermap unity-scope-soundcloud unity-scope-video-remote unity-scope-yahoostock
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to disable scopes that access the online data sources, the best option is to turn off the `Include online search results` option in the `Search` tab of the Privacy control panel.

Access to remote scopes (i.e. the "smart scope server") occurs within the home scope, and removing the `unity-scope-home` package would render the dash non-functional.

If you want to change the default for a system, you can follow the instructions from this question:

[How can I change default settings for new users?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65900/how-can-i-change-default-settings-for-new-users)

The contents of your overrides file should look something like:

```
[com.canonical.Unity.Lenses]
remote-content-search='none'
```