# How to setup "show-user-menu false" as default setting

Tags: unity, users, gsettings

Ubuntu unity displays users list:
[image]

I know that I can switch off this, using

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session user-show-menu false
```

or by using the dconf tools.

It works, but every user in the system has to do that, if he doesn't want to see all users list from system.

Do you know, how (and where) to set up this to not show users in menu as a default setting?

Comment: For setting it globally see `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas` or use an "override" file and new users:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/65900/how-can-i-change-default-settings-for-new-users  For current users you could put a gsettings in autostart (and you can remove it after said users have logged in once).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Copy the code below into an empty, file, save it as `nouserinfo.desktop`:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Exec=/bin/bash -c "sleep 10 && gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session user-show-menu false" 
   Name=NoUserInfo
   ```
2. Copy the file to `/etc/xdg/autostart`

From now on, the default will be set to not show the users. The setting will be applied shortly after log in.

#### Explanation

- The command to disable the list can be run on log in, by placing a `.desktop` file that runs your command in `~/.config/autostart`. This will however *only* run for one user.
- If you do the same, but put the `.desktop` file in `/etc/xdg/autostart`, the command will be run, equally what user logs in.
- The `sleep 10` is to make sure the command runs when the desktop is ready for it.

#### Exclude one user?

Simply put the file below in the user's `~/.config/autostart`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session user-show-menu true"
Name=NoUserInfo
```

Local versions of global `.desktop` files will overrule the global ones, also on Startup Applications' `.desktop` files.

Comment: you may want to add `Terminal=false` option.

Comment: @Serg `Terminal=false` is the default :)

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm Thank you! :) It was very helpful :)

Comment: @Krzysztof you are very welcome :)